# AngularJS - Save attribute value by default

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I use own tags 'repairwidth' with attribute 'width'. I get 'input' from this tag. Width = size.

First repairwidth tag must have width="50" always.
Second and third tags repairwidth have width="{{width}}"

I can change width from input with ng-model="width".
But width="50" doesn't work.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UF026UX3zsDPYS6Xq4Hq?p=preview)

Yes. I can use scope: {width: '@'} to fix it.
But in my application scope must have false value.
I can't use ng-init and ng-model.

Where is my mistake?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ang" ng-controller="ctrl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>width with scope: false</title>
</head>
<body>

<b>scope: false</b><br>
    <repairwidth width="50" ></repairwidth> 
    input must have size=50 always 
    <b>Doesn't work</b><br>

    <repairwidth width="{{width}}" ></repairwidth><br>

    <repairwidth width="{{width}}" ></repairwidth><br><br>


 <b>size for 2 & 3 inputs:</b> 
 <input type="text" ng-model="width" />
 I can change size for 2 & 3 inputs
 <b>Doesn't work</b><br>

 <b>not use ng-init and ng-model</b>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var ang = angular.module("ang", []);
    ang.directive('repairwidth', function(){
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          replace: true,
          transclude: false,
          scope: false,
          template: '<input type="text" size="{{width}}"/>'
            ,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {         
                attrs.$observe('width', function(value) {
                    if (value) element.attr('size',value);
                });
            }
        };
    });

    function ctrl($scope) {
        $scope.value= 'text';
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your directive scope is false, the directive inherits its scope from the parent.  That means all instances of your directive will use the same value of `width` that is set in the controller.  The width parameter that you are passing into the directive is essentially being ignored.

```
<repairwidth size="{{width}}" ></repairwidth>
```

does the same thing as

```
<repairwidth></repairwidth>
```

The easiest thing to do is to bind directly to the size parameter like this:

```
<repairwidth size="50" ></repairwidth> 
<repairwidth size="{{width}}" ></repairwidth>
<repairwidth size="{{width}}" ></repairwidth>
```

You don't even need the link function.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MdRW8cHqIOsujJX3VUqV?p=preview).